# how to hide django message after it is displayed for few seconds

Tags: javascript, django

For example, before redirect, I used

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'You have successfully updated your listing.')
```

Then the message will be automatically displayed after redirection, however the message will never disappear, may I know how to hide it after few seconds?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to write javascript code, use window [`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method to hide message after some time.

```
// suppose the `id` attribute of element is `message_container`.
var message_ele = document.getElementById("message_container");

setTimeout(function(){ 
   message_ele.style.display = "none"; 
}, 3000);
// Timeout is 3 sec, you can change it
```

> Put this code inside `base.html` at the bottom inside `<script>` tag, so whenever page reloaded after 3
>   sec it will make your message disappear.

Answer (score 3):

To hide only messages with a certain tag (e.g only INFO messages) you can use the following code inside your HTML document.

```
<script>
    // Get all info messages
    var info_messages = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-info');

    setTimeout(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < info_messages.length; i ++) {
            // Set display attribute as !important, neccessary when using bootstrap
            info_messages[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:none !important');
        }
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

the script:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        if ($('#msg').length > 0) {
            $('#msg').remove();
        }
    }, 2000)    // 2000 millisecond
</script>
```

the template:

```
<div id="msg">
    {{message}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is working fine for me:

```js
var message_ele = document.getElementById("msg");
setTimeout(function() {
  message_ele.style.display = "none";
}, 3000);
```

```html
<span id="msg">
{{messages}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve it this way.........

function fade_out() {$(".alert").fadeOut();};
setTimeout(fade_out, 3000);

Answer (score 0):

variable declaration outside of timeout function didn't work for me ,  declared inside and it  worked

```
 <script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        var hidemessage = document.getElementById("hide_message");
        hidemessage.style.display = "none";
    }, 2000);
</script>
```